Derivation of the volume of a half-sphere
I am trying to derive the volume of a half-sphere with a constant r using integration.
Integration
I first try to integrate  90 degrees from the top of the halfsphere down to the bottom plane of the halfsphere. This correctly gives me the formula for a quarter of a circle. $$\int_0^{\pi r/2} r d\theta = \frac{r^2\pi}4$$
I then try to integrate this area of a quarter circle 360 degrees along the circumference of the plane that bisects the sphere. (the bottom of the sphere)
$$\int_0^{\pi r2} r^2\pi d\phi = \frac{r^2\pi}4 = \frac{r^3\pi^2}2$$
But this is not the correct answer as the volume of a half sphere is $$V=\frac{2r^3\pi}3 $$
So where am I going wrong? I know the first integral is correct, but something happens in the 2nd integral that I dont understand. The idea should work as all it is "lifting" up an area (the quarter of a circle) through a distance $\phi$ which should give my volume?
I know I am technically not using degrees, but rather absolute distances, so forgive the maybe not completely stringent math - I am trying to reason on my own.
I also know the integral that gives the correct volume- however I am looking for an explanation as to why my own method is wrong.
Cheers

Your approach looks similar to Pappus's second centroid theorem. Maybe that gives some ideas? Though Pappus' formula requires calculating the distance travelled by the centroid.

Your approach would work if the area were translated by some distance $dx$, but a rotation is not a translation.

Its much easier and providing insight in the choice of coordinates, writing the integral as a an evaluation of a volume 3-form over a region decribed by an logical expression
$$\int _ {0 \lt \theta \lt \frac {\pi} {2}\ \land \ 0 \lt  \phi \lt 2\pi \ \land \ 0 \lt r \lt  R}  dr\ \wedge \ (r \ d\theta)\ \wedge \ (r\sin (\theta)\  d\phi)$$
of three unit lenght differentials in the 'right' order e.g. along the x$-$axis.
You may shift scalar factors to the front as coefficient. You my rotate differentials, preserving the determinantal order of the volume 3-form, in order to integrate the simplest inner form with the leftmost differential over its 1-d range
$$\int _ {0 \lt \theta \lt \frac {\pi} {2}\ \land \ 0 \lt  \phi \lt 2\pi \ \land \ 0 \lt r \lt  R} \left(r^2 \sin \theta \right) \ dr\ \wedge \ d\theta \wedge \   d\phi$$
Rotating $d\phi$ to the left yields
$$\int _ {0 \lt \theta \lt \frac {\pi} {2}\ \land \ 0 \lt  \phi \lt 2\pi \ \land \ 0 \lt r \lt  R} \left(r^2 \sin \theta \right) d\phi \ \wedge \ dr\ \wedge \ d\theta \wedge = 2\pi  \int _ {0 \lt \theta \lt \frac {\pi} {2}\  \ \land \ 0 \lt r \lt  R} \left(r^2 \sin \theta \right) \ dr\ \wedge \ d\theta  = 2 \pi \frac{R^3}{3}\ \int _ {0 \lt \theta \lt \frac {\pi} {2}\   } \ \sin \theta \ d \theta = \frac{2\pi R^3}{3}$$
If you want to express the volume by the area of the quarter circle times the length of the circle of its center of gravity, this  obviously   is
$$  V= \left(\pi \ \frac{R^2}{4}\right) \  2 \ \pi \ \left(\frac{4 R}{3 \pi } \right), $$
so its seems to be not so easy to evaluate center of the gravity vector.
